# How to Talk to Individual in Agoro Voice Chat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voice-recognition

I'm using Agoro io unity SDK to  implement voice chat feature in a game.  It is working. I want to know who are the users are connecting in  my Channel. and i have to personal chat with the individual person. For eg  in my channel there are  are 10 persons. Person1,Person2 to Person10. I have to chat with Person3 where other person should not hear.

How can i do it.

How can i do the personal chat with  desire person

Answer (score 1):

This thing you will have to manage yourself by creating a backend server

You'll then send a request to backend server that you want to call person3, the backend will create a new unique channel for you & person3 and send the same channel_name to both you and person3

then you & person3 both will join same unique channel provided by backend

this way you can create your own 1-1 voice chat using agora